# I am trying to start sidekiq server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run sidekiq server, but I found some warning.

I am running sidekiq server, but found error and warning and sidekiq server is not running even through I have updated all gems according to requirements.Below is error when I am staring sidekiq server using sidekiq.

```
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Try 'gem cleanup <gem>'
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:304:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated rack 3.0.8, but your Gemfile requires rack 2.2.4. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:25:in `block in setup'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:165:in `each'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:165:in `each'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `map'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `setup'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:159:in `with_level'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:111:in `silence'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
    from /home/dell/Documents/sidekiqlearning/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dell/Documents/sidekiqlearning/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /home/dell/Documents/sidekiqlearning/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dell/Documents/sidekiqlearning/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from /home/dell/Documents/sidekiqlearning/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
    from <internal:/home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:303:in `boot_application'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:42:in `run'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sidekiq-7.2.0/bin/sidekiq:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/sidekiq:25:in `load'
```

Comment: Which command do you use to start sidekiq?

Comment: Did you prepend `bundle exec` to your command as instructed?

Answer (score 1):

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

Just use this command, I hope it will run your sidekiq server.
And tell me one more thing, did you make `config/sidekiq.rb`?